# CSS pointer-events fails in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, debugging, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, pointer-events

There is a drop-down in my web application. This drop-down is user-defined (not using the `<select>` element). Inside this drop-down there is a down arrow. This arrow is creating by using background images on an absolutely positioned `span`. This `span` tag is blocking the click event of the drop-down. So, I've added `pointer-events:none` to the `span` tag. After adding this, it's working fine everywhere but in the Edge browser. Does Edge support `pointer-event: none`? If not,  what is the alternative for `pointer-event: none` in Edge.

Below is the code which I used:

```html
<div class="multi-dd" id="multi_dd_ddlProfession" role="application" cascadesto="ddlDiscipline">
    <input class="multi-dd-txt" id="txtProf" role="combobox" aria-readonly="false" aria-describedby="spMultiExit" style="width: 260px;" aria-label="Multi Select Control Professions " type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Select All">
    <span class="nir"></span>
</div>
```

```css
.nir{
    height: 28px; 
    margin-left: -30px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: Can you link to, or provide in your post, a working demo of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs which may be the root cause:

> FocusEvent Sequence should be: focusout, focusin, blur, focus.
>
> FocusEvent Sequence is: blur, focusout, focus, focusin.

and a no-repro test:

```css
#testID {pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://developer.microsoft.com">MS Dev</a></li>
  <li id="testID"><a href="http://example.com">example.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first version of Microsoft Edge was introduced in Windows 10 Build 10049. Pointer Events have been supported since Windows 10 Build 10240.

**References**

- ["Project Spartan" in the Windows Technical Preview build 10049 – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2015/03/30/project-spartan-in-the-windows-technical-preview-build-10049/)
- [Windows 10 Build 10240](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/desktop/10240/)
- [RemoteIE - Microsoft Edge Development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/)
- [HTML5test - How well does your browser support HTML5?](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/firefox/edge/chrome-52/ios-10.0.html)
- [CSS 'pointer-events: none' rule not working](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8295099/)
- [DOM Level 3: FocusEvent sequence](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/2222749/)
- [Edge raises "blur" event while "click" event processing is not completed](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5891473/)
- [Problem with focus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8016621/)
- [Click event not raised when Edge is not in focus](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8794543/)
- [Unifying touch and mouse: how Pointer Events will make cross-browsers touch support easy – David Rousset](https://www.davrous.com/2015/08/10/unifying-touch-and-mouse-how-pointer-events-will-make-cross-browsers-touch-support-easy/)